# Build errors on github's cyberduck

Tags: ant, cyberduck

Trying to build from cyberduck https://github.com/greenqloud/cyberduck from source i get some errors about azure and rococoa missing dependencies:

How should i proceed for a successful build?

```
compile:
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/build.xml:131: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 605 source files to /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/build/classes
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/AbstractCollectionListener.java
    [...]
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/aquaticprime/Receipt.java:35: warning: [deprecation] PKCS7SignedData in org.bouncycastle.jce has been deprecated
    [javac] import org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS7SignedData;
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/azure/AzureSession.java:33: error: package org.soyatec.windows.azure.authenticate does not exist
    [javac] import org.soyatec.windows.azure.authenticate.IAccessPolicy;
    [javac]                                              ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/azure/AzureSession.java:34: error: package org.soyatec.windows.azure.authenticate does not exist
    [javac] import org.soyatec.windows.azure.authenticate.SharedKeyCredentials;
    [javac]                                              ^
    [...]
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/azure/AzurePath.java:221: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected Acl convert(final ContainerAccessControl list) {
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ContainerAccessControl
    [javac]   location: class AzurePath
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/azure/AzureSession.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private BlobStorageRest client;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BlobProperties
    [javac]   location: class AzureSession.AzureContainer
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/azure/AzureSession.java:194: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                 throws StorageException {
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StorageException
    [javac]   location: class AzureSession.AzureContainer
    [...]
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSDictionary.java:22: error: package org.rococoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.ObjCClass;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSDictionary.java:23: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSUInteger;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSObject.java:22: error: package org.rococoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.ID;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSObject.java:23: error: package org.rococoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.Selector;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSObject.java:24: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSUInteger;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSObject.java:28: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] public abstract class NSObject extends org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSObject {
    [javac]                                                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSDictionary.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public interface _Class extends ObjCClass {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ObjCClass
    [javac]   location: class NSDictionary
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSArray.java:22: error: package org.rococoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.ObjCClass;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSArray.java:23: error: package org.rococoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.Rococoa;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSArray.java:24: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSUInteger;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSURL.java:22: error: package org.rococoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.ObjCClass;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSURL.java:23: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSNumber;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSDictionary.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger count();
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSDictionary
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSDictionary.java:194: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSDictionary initWithObjects_forKeys_count(NSObject objects, NSObject keys, NSUInteger cnt);
    [javac]                                                                                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSDictionary
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSObject.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract boolean respondsToSelector(Selector sel);
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Selector
    [javac]   location: class NSObject
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSObject.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSObject performSelector(Selector sel);
    [javac]                                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Selector
    [javac]   location: class NSObject
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSObject.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger hash();
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSObject
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSObject.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract boolean isEqual(ID anObject);
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ID
    [javac]   location: class NSObject
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSDictionary.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects_forKeys_count(NSObject objects, NSObject keys, NSUInteger cnt);
    [javac]                                                                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: interface _Class
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSArray.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public interface _Class extends ObjCClass {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ObjCClass
    [javac]   location: class NSArray
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSArray.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger count();
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSArray
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSArray.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSObject objectAtIndex(NSUInteger index);
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSArray
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSArray.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger indexOfObject(NSObject anObject);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSArray
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSArray.java:181: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger indexOfObjectIdenticalTo(NSObject anObject);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSArray
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSData.java:22: error: package org.rococoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.ObjCClass;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSData.java:23: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSUInteger;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:22: error: package org.rococoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.ObjCClass;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:23: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSInteger;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:24: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSUInteger;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSArray.java:267: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSArray initWithObjects_count(com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference objects, NSUInteger cnt);
    [javac]                                                                                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSArray
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSURL.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public interface _Class extends ObjCClass {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ObjCClass
    [javac]   location: class NSURL
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSNumber.java:22: error: package org.rococoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.ObjCClass;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSNumber.java:23: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSInteger;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSNumber.java:24: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSUInteger;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSValue.java:22: error: package org.rococoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.ObjCClass;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSValue.java:23: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSSize;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSArray.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         NSArray arrayWithObjects_count(NSObject objects, NSUInteger cnt);
    [javac]                                                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: interface _Class
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSData.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public interface _Class extends ObjCClass {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ObjCClass
    [javac]   location: class NSData
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSData.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger length();
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSData
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSData.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract void getBytes_length(com.sun.jna.Pointer buffer, NSUInteger length);
    [javac]                                                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSData
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSData.java:176: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSData initWithBytes_length(com.sun.jna.Pointer bytes, NSUInteger length);
    [javac]                                                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSData
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSData.java:188: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSData initWithBytesNoCopy_length_freeWhenDone(com.sun.jna.Pointer bytes, NSUInteger length, byte b);
    [javac]                                                                                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSData
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public interface _Class extends ObjCClass {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ObjCClass
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public static NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex(NSInteger value) {
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSRange.java:22: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.CFIndex;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSRange.java:23: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.CFRange;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSRange.java:24: error: package org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation does not exist
    [javac] import org.rococoa.cocoa.foundation.NSUInteger;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSRange.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class NSRange extends CFRange {
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]   symbol: class CFRange
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public static final NSUInteger NSNotFound = new NSUInteger(Native.LONG_SIZE == 4 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Long.MAX_VALUE);
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSIndexSet initWithIndex(NSUInteger value);
    [javac]                                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger count();
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger firstIndex();
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:113: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger lastIndex();
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger indexGreaterThanIndex(NSUInteger value);
    [javac]                                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger indexGreaterThanIndex(NSUInteger value);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger indexLessThanIndex(NSUInteger value);
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger indexLessThanIndex(NSUInteger value);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/foundation/NSIndexSet.java:131: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public abstract NSUInteger indexGreaterThanOrEqualToIndex(NSUInteger value);
    [javac]                                                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NSUInteger
    [javac]   location: class NSIndexSet
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/Session.java:125: warning: ValidatorException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac]                 if(e.getCause() instanceof sun.security.validator.ValidatorException) {
    [javac]                                                                  ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/http/HTTP3Session.java:118: warning: [deprecation] Protocol(String,SecureProtocolSocketFactory,int) in Protocol has been deprecated
    [javac]                     new org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol(host.getProtocol().getScheme(),
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/aquaticprime/Receipt.java:118: warning: [deprecation] PKCS7SignedData in org.bouncycastle.jce has been deprecated
    [javac]             PKCS7SignedData signature = new PKCS7SignedData(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/aquaticprime/Receipt.java:118: warning: [deprecation] PKCS7SignedData in org.bouncycastle.jce has been deprecated
    [javac]             PKCS7SignedData signature = new PKCS7SignedData(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/azure/AzurePath.java:528: warning: [deprecation] consumeContent() in AbstractHttpEntity has been deprecated
    [javac]                         public void consumeContent() throws IOException {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/cf/CFPath.java:411: warning: [deprecation] consumeContent() in AbstractHttpEntity has been deprecated
    [javac]                                 public void consumeContent() throws IOException {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/dav/DAVSession.java:224: warning: [deprecation] getReasonCode() in HttpException has been deprecated
    [javac]             if(e.getReasonCode() == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/dav/DAVSession.java:270: warning: [deprecation] getReasonCode() in HttpException has been deprecated
    [javac]             String status = HttpStatus.getStatusText(((HttpException) e).getReasonCode());
    [javac]                                                                         ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/dav/DAVResource.java:64: warning: [deprecation] setCredentials(String,String,Credentials) in HttpState has been deprecated
    [javac]         client.getState().setCredentials(null, httpURL.getHost(), hostCredentials);
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/source/ch/cyberduck/core/dav/DAVResource.java:170: warning: [deprecation] setUseExpectHeader(boolean) in ExpectContinueMethod has been deprecated
    [javac]         method.setUseExpectHeader(true);
    [javac]               ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 100 errors
    [javac] 11 warnings

BUILD FAILED
/Users/myuser/xcode/cyberduck/build.xml:131: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 6 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

The official source repository is at [svn.cyberduck.io](https://svn.cyberduck.io/trunk).